# How to create an instance of a discriminated union in TypeScript based on a provided type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, discriminated-union

Given the discriminated union `MyUnion`, I want to call a function `createMyUnionObject` with one of the `type`s of `MyUnion` and a value for `value` which must be the correct type.

```js
type MyUnion =
    {
        type: 'one'
        value: string
    } |
    {
        type: 'two',
        value: number
    } |
    {
        type: 'three',
        value: boolean
    };

function createMyUnionObject<
    T extends MyUnion['type'],
    MU extends Extract<MyUnion, { type: T }>,
    V extends MU['value']
>(type: T, value: V): MU {
    // Real code is conditional and may modify `value`, this is a simple example with the same problem I'm having
    return { type, value };
}
```

If you try calling `createMyUnionObject`, you'll see that TypeScript is correctly inferring the values outside the function definition.  That is, `createMyUnionObject('one', false)` will have the desired compile error `Argument of type 'false' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'`.

Within the function definition, however, I'm seeing `Type '{ type: T; value: V; }' is not assignable to type 'MU'.` and I don't understand why - how can I construct the object so that TypeScript is satisfied that it's the correct type?

Comment: Code in question uses TypeScript version 3.5.3, the latest version available when the question was asked was 3.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript isn't currently able to narrow the types of generic type parameters via control flow analysis.  Ideally I'd love to be able to write your function like this:

```
function createMyUnionObject<T extends MyUnion["type"]>(
    type: T,
    value: Extract<MyUnion, { type: T }>["value"]
): Extract<MyUnion, { type: T }> {
    return { type, value }; // error 
}
```

but we can't (note that we should only need one generic parameter... from `T` you should be able to compute the `value` and return types). Even though for any concrete value of `type` and its corresponding `value` the compiler can verify that `{type, value}` is assignable to `MyUnion`, it can't do it with generics.

---

One obstacle is that the compiler suspects that your `type` might be of the full union type `"one" | "two" | "three"`, and of course `value` could therefore be `string | number | boolean`, and then `{type, value}` might *not* be assignable to `MyUnion`:

```
const t = (["one", "two", "three"] as const)[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
const v = (["one", 2, true] as const)[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
createMyUnionObject(t, v); // uh oh
```

You want to tell the compiler: no, `T` can only be *either* `"one"`, *or* `"two"`, *or* `"three"`, but not the union of two or more of those.  That is not part of the language yet but it's [been requested](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808).  If that ever gets implemented it would still need to be combined with some kind of control flow analysis that did multiple passes over the body doing each possible narrowing in turn. I've [suggested this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25051) (and [related things](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581)) but again, it's not part of the language yet.

---

For now, I'd say that if you want your code to compile and move on, you will need to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to just tell the compiler that you know what you're doing is safe (and that you're just not going to worry about someone doing crazy `Math.random()` things like the code above):

```
function createMyUnionObject<T extends MyUnion["type"]>(
    type: T,
    value: Extract<MyUnion, { type: T }>["value"]
) {
    return { type, value } as any as Extract<MyUnion, { type: T }>; // assert
}
```

That should work, and you can use `createMyUnionObject()` as you'd like.  Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiCqA7Alge0VAvAKCnqA3rviaJAFxQDk6EVxJeAbgIYA2ArhJQM7ABOyRAHMGUAL5QAPmKKN8ZbtWAB3VFQA0Ykq05LEHALYAjCPzGSZJOfKiLKVYAAt+EOlttRdXSsdSo2CBZECwBubGwAMw5EAGNgNAxY1xZgCDgkRIB5YwArCHiAHgAVKAgADzTEABMeWAQUdABtACJFFoBdAD4ACjF7KGKPfG8lAFFK-hYijMbEDUI7cCVS8S7W0c7sAEpCMVdgDn4MAiXIBdGJKBY64JBruomBaeBC2cSF04HVrvDxCOwsXQfDsWCgPVatBaCzaamhUDaLjcnQeUCBiD42yaMFSTgAdJE2P5+D0cc48VMaqhDD1dgAqKAAZm2HXC6JBTDBEJaUIWACYFgIuB1UezgFiyfjCcTSbiKcFqtTaVAGczWYCUml3ugcvl4j1gBdtqEoAB6U1QDhOKCoJwRaJxBLoa6xWIQMDAYpOITCHocSjaxC7U7-aZuj1en09ZJBLUNbJ5ArAHqw1DwgCMfOZxqAA)